# How to increase characters in constant?

Tags: c, char

Here's just a sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char a;
int main(void)
{
a = 'ayy lmao';
printf("%c", a);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

When I execute, I get an error message saying that there are "too many characters in constant". How do i fix this and allow as many characters to be assigned to "a"?

Comment: "w" is a character array consisting of 'w' and the null character '\0'. Try `a =   'w';`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them

Comment: @AnirudhRamanathan Oh, that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"w"` is an array of characters, and it is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array as thr operand of assign operator.

It is assigned to `char`, so it will become an meaningless value in typical environments.

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a;
    a = 'w';
    printf("%c", a);
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char* a;
    a = "w";
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- You should use standard `int main(void)` instead of `main()`.
- Global variables shouldn't be used unless it is necessary.
- Character constants have type `int` in C, and `%c` for `printf()` accept `int` values. (`char` is automatically converted to `int` for variable-length arguments)
- `getchar();` is removed. Terminal softwares are useful to execute the program and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

In `C` You should define a character in Single Quote.

```
a = 'w';
```

Everything comes within a `"` is considered as a character array. It contains the character(s) followed by a terminating character `\0`.

Comment: But the printf isn't printing any of the contents of the string - it is printing one byte of the address of the string.  If he had said `printf("%c", *a)` then he would have seen what he wanted.

Comment: Yeah, but with his initial code, though he get couple of warnings, he should get some garbage printed out as an output.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah No, he won't. `a` has type `char`, so he will get a compilation error for dereferencing something not a pointer.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I am confused.  If there is a compilation error then how did it output 0?  Maybe there was a compilation error and he was running the previously successfully compiled version and that one was printing 0.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The original code do compiles and will print some value. *Your* suggestion `printf("%c", *a)` without any other changes will emit error. The string may be put somewhere page-aligned, so the least 8bit of the adress became `0`, I guess.